# Python regex match if surrounded

Tags: python, regex

I try to do a regex which consist to get the length of a specific word which is between personal pronouns and a '?' with findall. 
I did some research but didn't found how to check if a string start with ... AND ends with ... is there something like that ?

EDIT:
Here is an exemple : 
I have a long text, I want to find how many times the word "crazy" is asked as a question like this :

```
Are you crazy ? -> match because there a personal pronouns AND a '?' between the word
you are crazy ? -> No, because the word is between a verb and a '?'
Is he crazy ? -> match because there a personal pronouns AND a '?' between the word
```

Comment: Please post you input and desired output.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you want. Provide us with some examples: what should match your regex, and what should not

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Smells like you need natural language processing, not regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do the trick if you don't want to match the "you are crazy ?" form:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = '(?:I|you|he|she|it|we|they|me|him|her|it|us|them) (?:an? )?(\w\w+)\s?\?'
>>> re.findall(pat, "is he available ? Isn't she a jerk ?")
['available', 'jerk']
```

Otherwise, this might work :

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = '(?:I|you|he|she|it|we|they|me|him|her|it|us|them)((?: [a-z]+)+)\s?\?'
>>> filt = re.findall(pat, "is he available ? Isn't she a jerk ? you are crazy ?")
>>> filt
[' available', ' a jerk', ' are crazy']
#Then to get the number of times crazy appeared in a question :
>>> len([el for el in filt if "crazy" in el])
1
```

For this second method, you actually do two filter, one to extract everything between personal pronoun and "?". Then you filter a second time to count how many times the target word is in these question forms. But for the latter a much propper way would be to use another regex, cause my actual dirty way would count "notsocrazy" as a match

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The goal you are after seems more complicated than a regular expression can do justice, but here's one that could help:

```
import re

word_to_match="crazy"
pattern = "[^\\.\\?]*\\s(he|she|you|it|they|I)\\s({})\\s?\\?".format(word_to_match)


print (re.findall(pattern, "Are you crazy? You are crazy? Is he crazy?"))
```